# Call to undefined function App\Repositories\array_build()

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3

One of my colleagues wrote this code that builds an array for a chart:

```
$results = array_build(range($days - 1, 0), function ($k, $v) use ($dateFormat) {
            return [Carbon::today()->subDays($v)->format($dateFormat), [
                '0' => 0,
                '1' => 0
            ]];
        });
```

I just finished an upgrade from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3 and now get the following exception:

> Call to undefined function App\Repositories\array_build()

I'm not exactly sure how his code works (hence I do not find the array_build method) and therefore cannot get it back working.

Comment: hmm have u tried using array_fill ?

Comment: can you post the composer.json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_build()` [was dropped in version 5.3](https://www.dunebook.com/features-expected-in-laravel-5-3/), which is why you can't use out of the box after your migration.

> array_build() helper is also removed from the framework as it’s no longer used anywhere in the core.

You can get the function [from the source](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-helpers/blob/master/src/helpers.php#L65):

```
<?php
function array_build($array, Closure $callback)
{
    $results = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        list($innerKey, $innerValue) = call_user_func($callback, $key, $value);
        $results[$innerKey] = $innerValue;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

*Note: the source is unofficial, there's no mention of dropping the function in the [official migration doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)*

Comment: Ah thanks, that's why I did not find anything about it.

Comment: this should be the right answer. anyways added how to in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a helper method. 
try running

```
composer dumpautoload
```

if that doesn't solve can you try and see whether composer.json contains the file containing helper method autoloaded like below. helper file should contain the method array_build. name of the file might not be helpers.php

```
"files":["app/helpers.php"].
```

as @ishegg has mentioned it has been dropped. so if you want your code to work here is a way to do it.

create a file like this in project root or somewhere

**helpers.php**

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists('array_build'))
{
    /**
     * Build a new array using a callback.
     *
     * @param  array     $array
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return array
     */
    function array_build($array, Closure $callback)
    {
        $results = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            list($innerKey, $innerValue) = call_user_func($callback, $key, $value);
            $results[$innerKey] = $innerValue;
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```

and in **composer.json** autoload the file like this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        .....
    },
    "files": [
        "helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Comment: I'm aware that this is an helper method, my issue is that I cannot find it. I need to get the code back working, probably without that helper method. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: search for  something like
if (! function_exists('array_build')) {